# Encode NSArray or NSDictionary using NSCoder

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nskeyedarchiver, gamekit

I was wondering whether or not it is possible to use the NSCoder method:

```
- (void)encodeObject:(id)objv forKey:(NSString *)key
```

to encode either an instance of NSArray or NSDictionary. If not how do you go about encoding them? I am trying to use NSKeyedArchived / NSKeyedUnarchiver to send data between phones using GameKit. I tried it and cannot seem to retrieve the string I stored in my array. The packet class I made comes through along with the packet type integer, but not the data in the array it seems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a custom NSManagedObject.... I think I have to use XML or JSON for this, but I need to learn how D:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NSKeyedArchiver/Unarchiver should encode and decode NSArrays and NSDictionaries with no problem. If your packet class you've created implements the NSCoding protocol, you need to explicitly call `[encodeObject:`*`myNsArray`*`forKey:@"stringsArray"]` in your `-encodeWithCoder:` method (assuming that *myNsArray* is the name of the instance variable in your packet object you want to encode).  But then the archiver and NSArray should take care of the rest of it. If you're doing this, it would be helpful to hear more about the layout of your classes and who's calling who when encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 32):

If the array or dictionary is the root object you should do

```
NSData * encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:someArray];
```

or

```
BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:someArray toFile:filePath];
```

If it is an instance variable of a custom class, in the `-encodeWithCoder:` method should do

```
[coder encodeObject:someArray forKey:@"someArray"];
```

and then in the `-initWithCoder:` method

```
someArray = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"someArray"] retain];
```

Answer (score 21):

What kind of objects are you storing in the array? Make sure that all objects stored in the array implement the NSCoding protocol.