# NSKeyedArchiver not retaining the order of array elements

Tags: ios, iphone, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I am currently saving array with custom objects using archiever

```
 NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cache];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"KP_SEARCH_CACHE"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

But the order of the objects when I retrieve the array is random. i need to retain the original order. It would be of great help if someone could recommend something

Comment: Is your NSArray the cache variable?

Comment: You should not have a problem serializing an NSArray and maintaining the order. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226390/encode-nsarray-or-nsdictionary-using-nscoder

Comment: yes it is a variable..

Comment: It should work. Can you post some code?

Comment: Do you sure, that you save array in your custom order? :-) Double re-check it

Comment: @DanLoughney ,Vitality ... This is a kind of question we need to down vote... The problem was something else... NSKeyedArchiver worked just fine...