# Convert NSArray into NSData iOS objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver

This is my code but i can't getting the data

```
NSData *wrtData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:my_Array];
```

Comment: Have you tried to print my_Array and is it printing proper data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226390/encode-nsarray-or-nsdictionary-using-nscoder Check this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286212/how-to-convert-nsarray-to-nsdata See in the above link you'll get the solution

Comment: @Inder please check my answer and reply..

Comment: You might want to add more code: an exact way to recreate your my_Array for example. Main problem is: objects in your array don't conform to <NSCoding>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this sample:

```
   NSArray *mapPoints = @[
                      @{ @"latitude":@"10.010490",
                          @"longitude":@"76.360779",
                          @"altitude":@"30.833334",
                          @"timestamp":@"11:17:23",
                          @"speed":@"0.00",
                          @"distance":@"0.00"
                      },
                      @{
                          @"latitude":@"10.010688",
                          @"longitude":@"76.361378",
                          @"altitude":@"28.546305",
                          @"timestamp":@"11:19:26",
                          @"speed":@"1.614",
                          @"distance":@"198.525711"
                      }
                      ];

NSLog(@"Countries array = %@",mapPoints);
NSData *mapPointsData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:mapPoints];
NSLog(@"countries data=%@",mapPointsData);
NSLog(@"mapPointsData to mapPointsArray = %@",[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:mapPointsData]);
```

### Github link:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/JsonArrayToNSData

Comment: my array is in json formate, when archivedDataWithRootObject: then i got an error

reason: '-[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f2b550

Comment: i have the same json formate but on my end its not working, MY Array Count 4000, i got error :::    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x160ebed0

Comment: shall i add sample what i have done(same as the answer)?

Comment: sure @Sathi Reddy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a `NSArray` to `NSData` you should make sure that all objects inside this array conform to [NSCoding protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoding). Same goes for `NSDictionary`.